# Git: Adding files that don't belong to a submodule in a superproject?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git superproject that has 3 submodules in it. I want to add pictures to it. I don't really feel like I need a repo just for the pictures. Would it be bad practice to have the pictures in the superproject without them being a part of a submodule?

Comment: Do the submodules use those pictures from an explicit path?

Comment: No. The submodules do not necessarily use the pictures.